# Do employers favor Premium LinkedIn Job Seekers over ordinary Job Seekers?

Tags: job-search, linkedin

An option on LinkedIn for ordinary (non-paying) account-holders is to upgrade to Premium (paying) status. There are [various benefits](https://www.linkedin.com/premium/survey/) including "Move your job applications to the top of the recruiter's list." and "Stand out in search results with a premium icon on your profile."

**preliminary question**
How do things appear to employers when

- they search for potential new employees?
- several job seekers apply via the Apply button?

**main question**
Assuming employers know the difference between "ordinary" and Premium job seekers, how does that affect their judgement?

I'm *not* asking about any other possible benefits to the job seeker, such as InMail Messages or Who's Viewed Your Profile.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I've worked in professional recruitment for over a decade and have been a LinkedIn member since 2003.  MY team and I use LinkedIn on a daily basis to recruit talent. I can say with near certainty the level of account you have is of little to no importance in getting our attention.

The more your LinkedIn profile accurately reflects your skills, experience, certifications and education the more likely you are to attract attention.

Answer (score 12):

I got a free month of premium when I got made redundant from a job a few years ago.  To be honest it made little difference, few recruiters actually noticed, the ones that did took the line "you are paying a lot each month to advertise you need a job so I'll lo-ball you as you're desperate".

This may have changed in the time since, and the "move to top" also depends on the recruiter paying for their premium service as well.

Comment: If you are employed the premium icon is also a bit like having a big flashing neon sign saying "I'm leaving"

Answer (score 2):

I see no reason why that would make a differnce. When I hire,  I am concerned about your qualifications not how you use social media.

Answer (score 0):

Opting for the premium service can work in many ways. As Mark Chapman said it could back fire with you appearing to be desperate but it could also mean that you are serious about your next job. For many reasons, recruiters across linkedin get numerous connection requests each day. Due to this it may become difficult for the recruiters to differentiate between a casual connection and a serious connection.

Most corporations these days want to look at your linkedin profile before calling you about open positions. This does not necessarily mean that a premium member would somehow get more attention than a usual linkedin account.